# Firebase Queries Collection

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

so I have a collection of schedule in the firestore like this

/schedule/(name schedule)

if user make a ticket Iam store that to

/schedule/(name schedule)/ticket/(id ticket)/ticket data etc
but I cant make Queries filter to ticket collection before access all my Queries in the schedule

is there a way to optimize this ??

I thing about make a special field to Queries like collection('schedule').where('userOrdered', arrayContain: user)

but thats will need to make another field and double queries and If i store ticket data to User account, I cant make changes to schedule if user already ordered it before

Comment: Can you provide code for the query, and example for the structure? ... and one more thing if you try to query on more than two levels of structure where the id changes, then in realtime you can't (I am happy to describe it more just need more details )

Comment: If you know the path to what you want to query, it can be done. But it's not clear what exactly you're asking. What is (id ticket)? Another collection? Something else? Why is it there instead of another collection? What kind of queries do you want to run? Do you have some code that isn't working?

Comment: I want to access all my collection under ticket 
but the thing is I must access upper level collection right
otherwise I cant access the upperdown level 
because (nameSchedule) is generated

Comment: @TonyHart Please edit your question, provide your code and query that you are trying to to resolve the issue.